# tikz - command node - text

Tags: tikz-pgf

my MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2*pi] 
    \draw[xstep=pi/4, ystep=0.5, dashed, color=gray] (-0.1,-1.6) grid (2*pi,1.6); 
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$t$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$i(t)$}; 
    \node[below left](0,0){$0$};
    \draw[color=blue, smooth]   plot (\x,{sin(\x r)})    node[below right] {$i(t)$}; 
    \node[below left] at (2,2) {$i(t) = I_0\sin\omega t$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the last command I try to put the text `$i(t) = I_0\sin\omega t$` at coordinate (2,2), but the result does not match my expectations. Where is problem? How to insert text at a certain position without depending on previous commands?

I got this image:
[image]

I expected that the text `$i(t) = I_0\sin\omega t$` will be more right.

Comment: What are your expectations? For me, the node is placed correctly `below left` of the coordinate `(2,2)`. Where do you expect it to appear?

Comment: I added a picture. Yours is the same?

Comment: Yes: it is exactly the same. Where do you want to place `$i(t) = I_0\sin\omega t$`?

Comment: I also got the same picture.  I added `\fill (2,2) circle[radius=2pt];` to check where the point `(2,2)` is and the text is placed "below left" of that point.  Perhaps that point isn't where you expected it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be *more right*, then you should specify `below right` and not `below left`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2*pi] 
    \draw[xstep=pi/4, ystep=0.5, dashed, color=gray] (-0.1,-1.6) grid (2*pi,1.6); 
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$t$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$i(t)$}; 
    \node[below left](0,0){$0$};
    \draw[color=blue, smooth]   plot (\x,{sin(\x r)})    node[below right] {$i(t)$}; 
    \node[below right] at (2,2) {$i(t) = I_0\sin\omega t$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can find more information on positioning nodes in the [pgfmanual, section 16.5](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: Or perhaps just `below`, or perhaps nothing at all (depending on how we should interpret "more right"; personally, I'd put nothing at all as I think it should be a bit higher than it is).

Comment: @AndrewStacey: yeah, it sure depends on the requirements – I can only guess what they are supposed to be.

Comment: From the checkmark it appears that you guessed correctly!  Probably worth directing the questioner to Section 16.5 of the PGF manual (version 2.10 - might be elsewhere in different versions) on positioning nodes using anchors.